# noICE and GNU ARM assembler

Tags: debugging, assembly, arm

We are doing ARM assembly language programming at college and I want to setup an environment that allows me to run/simulate simple ARM programs on my computer.

I got the noICE debugger for ARM and the GNU ARM toolchain installed. How would I go about getting the most simple ARM assembly program loaded into noICE so that I can single step through the instructions?

I tried assembling this very simple sequence into an ELF file using arm-hitex-elf-as -o out.elf c:\test.s

```
main:
    mov r0, #10
    mov r1, #20
    add r2, r1, r0
    cmp r2, r1
    beq main    
.end
```

It generates the out.elf file but when I try to load it into noICE I keep getting the error message "Elf Error: ELF file is not executable format".

Please help a noob out guys, thanks!!

Edit: the assembler only generated a relocatable object file. feeding that object file to arm-hitex-elf-ld yielded the actual executable file which now works fine in noICE.

Comment: Do update your results based on my answer as what I've answered is a guess as I've never used noICE

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!! I figured out the answer to the problem

Comment: And what is that?? I'm curious to know

Comment: Hi I have edited my original posting

Comment: Cool that you solved your problem. We should have noted the `as` at the end.